# Return original URL when using reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, host, apache2.4

We are using reverse proxy to allow users from outside the firewall to access to services on an internal server. However although we use the `ProxyPreserveHost` directive, requests with the URL `http://project.domain.com/index.html` result in `http://internal.server/index.html` instead of the expected `http://project.domain.com/index.html`.

Here is our virtual host definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName "https://project.domain.com"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/our.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/our.key

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://internal.server:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://internal.server:80/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the target of the `ProxyPass` was itself redirected to `https://internal.server`.

When we changed `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` target to `https://internal.server` (bypassing the redirection), the `ProxyPreserveHost` directive worked.